# Process Data from Stored Procedure Returning Multipe Tables

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple tables. I need to execute that stored procedure inside another one to get the data for the further processing of it.

I know that it is possible to get the result into a table, but it only works when a single table is returned. Is there any way I can get the results of the first returned table, or all of the tables, and save it in a variable or temp table?

Comment: If all the datasets are the same, you could do this, if they are all different, you're going to need a design change.

Comment: Nope, actually all the datasets are of a different structure.

Comment: Then you're going to need to change your design.

Comment: A few years ago I was also looking for a way to get the second result set of a stored procedure using only T-SQL, but couldn't find a way to do that. perhaps I just didn't find it then, or maybe there is a way now, I don't know.

Comment: I don't, believe anything *new* has been added in 2017/2019, @ZoharPeled . I haven't completely read all the new "features" in 2019, however, I also feel that it would have been something that would have popped up in articles during its Preview if such functionality had been added.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible using pure T-SQL. The tSQLt Unit Test system allows you to grab individual result sets from stored procedures for testing purposes, but it does that using CLR procedures.

Comment: I'll probably break the existing procedure and add an optional output parameter, but still, it's interesting if there is a solution.

Comment: @Larnu - A few years ago -> 2008 version. But I agree, I think we would see this new feature somewhere if they added it.

Comment: Add an additional parameter(@save_to_tables bit) to your sp and analize it within sp. If @save_to_tables = 1 make insert into temp tables that are not defined in this sp but in outer sp. When you need to reuse these results, create appropriate tables in outer sp and then call the inner sp with save_to_tables = 1